# call Rcpp function in R

Tags: r, rcpp

below is the R code where functions stl_example_model  and stl_example_jacobian  in a dll are referenced.

```
library(RcppSundials)
library(microbenchmark)

stl_example_model = getNativeSymbolInfo(name = "example_model_stl",
                                        PACKAGE = "RcppSundials")$address
stl_example_jacobian = getNativeSymbolInfo(name = "example_jacobian_stl",
                                           PACKAGE = "RcppSundials")$address

simulationstl = wrap_cvodes(times = 1:5, 
                            states_ = rep(1.0,5), 
                            parameters_ = 0.1, 
                            forcings_data_ =list(cbind(1:3600,1:3600)),
            ..., 
                            model_ = example_model, jacobian_ = example_jacobian)
```

I have sourced another function (test.cpp) using the Rcpp::sourceCpp. How do I a make a reference to this function (similar to stl_example_model) using Rcpp?

Test.cpp

```
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

extern "C" {
  array<vector<double>, 2> example_model_stl(const double& t, const vector<double>& states, 
            const vector<double>& parameters, const vector<double>& forcings) {

    vector<double> derivatives(states.size());  
    for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
      derivatives[i] = -states[i]*parameters[0];
    }
    vector<double> observed{forcings[0]};
    array<vector<double>, 2> output{derivatives, observed};
    return output;
  }

  arma::mat example_jacobian_stl(const double& t, const vector<double>& states, 
            const vector<double>& parameters, const vector<double>& forcings) {
    arma::mat output = arma::eye(states.size(), states.size());
    output = -parameters[0]*output;
    return output;
  }

  array<vector<double>, 2> example_dae_stl(const double& t, const vector<double>& states, 
            const vector<double>& derivatives, const vector<double>& parameters, 
            const vector<double>& forcings) {

    vector<double> residues(states.size());  
    residues[0] = -0.04*states[0] + 1e4*states[1]*states[2];
    residues[1] = -residues[0] - 3e7*states[1]*states[1] - derivatives[1];
    residues[0] = residues[0] - derivatives[0];
    residues[2] = states[0] + states[1] + states[2] - 1.0;
    vector<double> observed{forcings[0]};
    array<vector<double>, 2> output{residues, observed};
    return output;
  }

};
```

Comment: The [`RcppSundials`](https://github.com/AleMorales/RcppSundials.R) package is dormant. I'm not sure it would be wise to count on this package for an analysis.

Comment: Besides that,  you know how to access code from it -- as it is in package form.  So do the same with your code:  Make it into a package.

Comment: @coatless. I know but this is really about sundials not the R package wrapper. I hope the wrapper dont break when updating the Sundials library.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel . I finally  grasped what you have been posting a few times. I created a package using RcppArmadillo, That works very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make a lot of sense to use a package as mentioned by Dirk in the comments. However, it is not strictly necessary.

1. The `PACKAGE` argument of `getNativeSymbols` is actually optional. All loaded DLLs are searched if it is omitted.
2. Compiling your example produces the warning

   > No Rcpp::export attributes or RCPP_MODULE declarations found in source

   As a consequence the produced DLL is not loaded into R's memory. You can change this by adding an exported dummy function.

Example:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

extern "C" {
    array<vector<double>, 2> example_model_stl(const double& t, const vector<double>& states, 
                                               const vector<double>& parameters, const vector<double>& forcings) {

        vector<double> derivatives(states.size());  
        for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
            derivatives[i] = -states[i]*parameters[0];
        }
        vector<double> observed{forcings[0]};
        array<vector<double>, 2> output{derivatives, observed};
        return output;
    }

    arma::mat example_jacobian_stl(const double& t, const vector<double>& states, 
                                   const vector<double>& parameters, const vector<double>& forcings) {
        arma::mat output = arma::eye(states.size(), states.size());
        output = -parameters[0]*output;
        return output;
    }

    array<vector<double>, 2> example_dae_stl(const double& t, const vector<double>& states, 
                                             const vector<double>& derivatives, const vector<double>& parameters, 
                                             const vector<double>& forcings) {

        vector<double> residues(states.size());  
        residues[0] = -0.04*states[0] + 1e4*states[1]*states[2];
        residues[1] = -residues[0] - 3e7*states[1]*states[1] - derivatives[1];
        residues[0] = residues[0] - derivatives[0];
        residues[2] = states[0] + states[1] + states[2] - 1.0;
        vector<double> observed{forcings[0]};
        array<vector<double>, 2> output{residues, observed};
        return output;
    }

};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void dummy() {}

/***R
getNativeSymbolInfo("example_model_stl")$address
*/
```

Output:

```r
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('58881676.cpp')

> getNativeSymbolInfo("example_model_stl")$address
<pointer: 0x7fd438ed5f80>
attr(,"class")
[1] "NativeSymbol"
```

This way it should be possible to use such functions together with RcppSundials.

Comment: Thanks for the post! This solutions works very well. Both ways are quite slow. But that is a small worry.

Comment: What's with the `ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11` ?  Isn't that a retrograde step, possibly leading to worse performance? Recent releases of GCC and Clang use C++14 as the default dialect.

Comment: @mtall That was just copy&paste from the OP‘s code. I can only assume it was there for a reason.